# Não consigo alcançar minha sub página passando por url amigável

Tags: php, url-amigável

O .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^imagine/([^/]+)/([^.]+)$ ver_imaginew_agora.php&id=$1&titulo=$2
RewriteRule ^portifolio/([^/]+)/([^.]+)$ ver_portifilio.php&id=$1&titulo=$2
```

Modo como eu passo o link

```
<a href="portifolio/<?php echo $lista['id']; ?>/<?php echo $lista['titulo']; ?>">
```

ele não encontra a página que está lá.

Comment: Cuidado ao montar a URL pois `$lista['titulo']` tem que estar preparada para compor uma URL, isto é, sem acentos, espaços, simbolos como `?`, `!`, `>`, `&`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Há um erro após os nomes dos arquivos, invés de utilizar o '&' após o '.php' deve-se utilizar '?'. Após o primeiro parâmetro utiliza-se o '&'.

Segue abaixo a correção:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^imagine/([^/]+)/([^.]+)$ ver_imaginew_agora.php?id=$1&titulo=$2
RewriteRule ^portifolio/([^/]+)/([^.]+)$ ver_portifilio.php?id=$1&titulo=$2
```

Comment: Deu derto demais!!! obrigado, só queria saber como eu coloco o link pra voltar dentro de uma pagina normal .. por exemplo.. lá tá assim ..<a href="index.php">voltar</a> e ele tá passando assim.. http://www.imaginew.com.br/imagine/9/Envelopamento%20de%20Ve%C3%ADculo%20-%2012/11/index.php

Comment: Neste caso você têm que colocar uma barra antes de index.php para que o navegador entenda que você quer ir para a página index.php a partir da raiz do site. Tente substituir seu link por <a href="/index.php">voltar</a>